# ASP.NET Core 3.1 MVC app - search views in subdirectory

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I know there is an area feature. But I think that is just to much for what I really need.

- I have an `netcoreapp3.1` build from the MVC template
- I have a `HomeController` (namespace `My.Project.Controllers`)
- I also have a `SettingsController` (namespace `My.Project.Controllers.Admin`)
- In my `_Layout.cshtml` I link to the controller like this (generated link is `https://localhost:5001/admin/settings/` as expected.

```html
@if (User.IsInRole("admin"))
{
    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle text-dark" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button"
            data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            Admin
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-item" asp-area="" asp-controller="settings" asp-action="Index">Settings</a>
        </div>
    </li>
}
```

I also added the first `MapControllerRoute` to my `Startup.Configure` method

```cs
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
            name: "admin",
            pattern: "admin/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
            );
    endpoints.MapRazorPages();

    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "default",
        pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    endpoints.MapRazorPages();
});
```

The controller is invoked and

```cs
public class SettingsController : Controller
{
    private readonly ISettingsProvider settingsProvider;

    public SettingsController(ISettingsProvider settingsProvider)
    {
        this.settingsProvider = settingsProvider;
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        var settings = settingsProvider.GetSettings();
        return View(settings);
    }
}
```

Now I get the following error

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
> InvalidOperationException: The view 'Index' was not found. The following locations were searched:
> /Views/Settings/Index.cshtml
> /Views/Shared/Index.cshtml
> /Pages/Shared/Index.cshtml

As I already said, I also tried using Areas but that would require me to put my files inside an `Areas` folder with its own `Views` folder and viewstart etc.

I worked a lot with nancy fx and I am used to the convention that views for `My.Project.Modules.Admin.SettingsModule` are searched inside `Views/Admin/Settings` first.

How do I achieve the same with ASP.NET Core MVC (for `My.Project.Controllers.Admin.SettingsController` search views in `Views/Admin/Settings`?)

```
- src/
  - Views/
    - Home/
      - Index.cshtml
    - Admin/
       - Settings/
         - Index.cshtml
  - Controllers/
    - Admin/
        SettingsController.cs
    - HomeController.cs
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Settings", "Admin" FormMethod.Get))
{
   @if (User.IsInRole("admin"))
   {
<li class="nav-item dropdown">
    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle text-dark" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button"
        data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        Admin
    </a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
        <a class="dropdown-item" asp-area="" asp-controller="settings" asp-action="Index">Settings</a>
    </div>
</li>
```

}
}

Answer (score 0):

I believe your issue is in the creation of the routing.

There is more information about this [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/areas?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

For your current configuration I think, if you change your pattern it will solve your issue

```
 pattern: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
```

Answer (score 0):

## Solved

There are four things that I had to do.

First, I had to setup a new Controller Route inside `Startup.Configure`

```cs
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "areas",
                pattern: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}");

        endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
            name: "default",
            pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

        endpoints.MapRazorPages();
    });
```

Second, I needed to tell my Controller that it belongs to the admin area.

```cs
[Area("admin")]
public class SettingsController : Controller
{
}
```

In my layout I had to set the `asp-area` property to `admin`

```html
<a class="dropdown-item" asp-area="admin" asp-controller="settings" asp-action="Index">Settings</a>
```

but that was not enough since the default will only search in the following locations:

```
InvalidOperationException: The view 'Index' was not found. The following locations were searched:

/Areas/admin/Views/Settings/Index.cshtml
/Areas/admin/Views/Shared/Index.cshtml
/Views/Shared/Index.cshtml
/Pages/Shared/Index.cshtml
```

So I had to add this to the `ConfigureServices` method.

```
services.Configure<RazorViewEngineOptions>(options =>
    {
        // {0} - Action Name
        // {1} - Controller Name
        // {2} - Area Name
        options.AreaViewLocationFormats.Add("/Views/{2}/{1}/{0}.cshtml");
    });
```